# java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

Tags: android, json, object, socket.io

I'm new to android and am trying to create an app, using socket.io running on background service, but i get an error and couldn't find a solution on the internet or i don't understand the problem enough since my lack of experience with android (and objects).

```
mSocket.on("start tracking", new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {

                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                 long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                        String id;
                        try {
                            id = data.getString("id");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            return;
                        }
                        //cancel();
                        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0 > 60 * 1000) {
                            cancel();
                        } else {
                            //do my stuff
                            String deviceId = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),
                                    Settings.System.ANDROID_ID);
                              if(id == deviceId){
                                mSocket.emit("emmitting location", deviceId, latitude, longitude);
                              }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 0, 1000);
            }
        });
```

**Edit:**
I didn't realize i wasn't passing JSON object through my server. Thanks to @cybersam for clearing everything and explaining the whole situation patiently. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is not derived from `JSONObject`. So, you need to convert the `String` instance into a new `JSONObject` instance.

Try this:

```
    mSocket.on("start tracking", new Emitter.Listener() { 

        @Override 
        public void call(final Object... args) {

          timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                @Override 
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data;
                    String id;
                    try {
                        data = new JSONObject((String) args[0]);
                        id = data.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        return; 
                    } 
                    //cancel(); 
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0 > 60 * 1000) {
                        cancel();
                    } else { 
                        //do my stuff 
                        String deviceId = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),
                                Settings.System.ANDROID_ID); 
                        mSocket.emit("emmitting location", deviceId, latitude, longitude);
                    } 
                } 
            }, 0, 1000); 
        } 
    });
```

[EDIT]

On the other hand, if your input data is just a `String`, and not a JSON string, do this:

```
    mSocket.on("start tracking", new Emitter.Listener() { 

        @Override 
        public void call(final Object... args) {

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
             long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                @Override 
                public void run() { 
                    String id = (String) args[0];
                    //cancel(); 
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0 > 60 * 1000) {
                        cancel();
                    } else { 
                        //do my stuff 
                        String deviceId = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),
                                Settings.System.ANDROID_ID); 
                        mSocket.emit("emmitting location", deviceId, latitude, longitude);
                    } 
                } 
            }, 0, 1000); 
        } 
    });
```

NOTE: You never actually use `id` anywhere...

Comment: Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException

Comment: It wouldn't work. The app won't crash but wasn't sending location, so i put `mSocket.emit("new message", e);` in the `catch(JSONException e)` and got this `org.json.JSONException: Value c923f2446ae9d398 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: OK, I guess you are using https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java (which you should have stated in your question). The `e` value that you are emitting is probably not a legal JSON string, but "c923f2446ae9d398". You need to make sure you emit a legal JSON string (and it must contain an `id` property).

Comment: Yeah i thought i should mention that, but i think it was obvious with the .emit stuff. And yes it is not a json string, just a single value. Here's my js code on the server `socket.on('starting tracking', function(id){io.emit('start tracking', id);});`

Comment: So, why were you trying to treat a non-JSON string as a JSON string?

Comment: I was just following the example from the official website. I'm blind new to android and i can't get the heck of it.. how do i get that id value that was emitted by the server?

Comment: Oook. That worked like a charm. I'm actually going to use the id to filter the emits. If the sent id matches the devices' then start the emit. If not - do nothing. Thank you kind sir! We need more patient people like you to help us noobs :) Cudos

Comment: Hi I m fesing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Java seems to have a limitation on how it handles a cast to a String inside a JSONObject instantiation.

So you're better off doing something like this using java String.valueOf() method for you conversion:

```
mSocket.on("start tracking", new Emitter.Listener() { 

    @Override 
    public void call(final Object... args) {

      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            @Override 
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data;
                String id;
                try {
                    // Update conversion like this below
                    data = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(args[0]));
                    id = data.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    return; 
                } 
                //cancel(); 
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0 > 60 * 1000) {
                    cancel();
                } else { 
                    //do my stuff 
                    String deviceId = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),
                            Settings.System.ANDROID_ID); 
                    mSocket.emit("emmitting location", deviceId, latitude, longitude);
                } 
            } 
        }, 0, 1000); 
    } 
});
```